# Iframe in PHP script repeats again and again on HostGator

Tags: php, iframe, hosting, web-hosting

I developed a PHP application having a iframe in it to load different kind of forms as per different conditions. I developed and tested this application in my development environment having PHP 5.3 version. To make this live, I hosted it on my HostGators account. My Hostgators account is running with PHP 5.2.17 version. When I run the script in web browser, it repeats iframes as shown in the image attached.

[image]

The red rectangles represents individual iframes. The script should show only one iframe but it repeats again and again.

Another problem with this is the searched item cannot search and display in resulting tables below the search box.

I tested this on Yahoo hosting, my several linux, windows servers, it works in all of them fine. What could be problem with HostGator environment. Thanking you for reply.

Comment: I used PHP 5.3 in development environment and there is PHP 5.2.17 on HostGator is there compatibility issue? ["Oldstable PHP version (5.2) is not compatible with new development version (5.3, 5.4)" http://code.google.com/p/php52-backports/]

Answer (score 0):

The target of this form is the same page that has the IFRAME. It should be the target of the iframe itself, otherwise you will keep this recursion.

If you provide the code, we can fix it for you. ;)

Editing with the code provided:

```
<iframe id="iframe_form" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0px" 
        marginheight="0px" topmargin="0px" leftmargin="0px" 
        align="center" height="500px" name="iframe_form" 
        scrolling="auto" 
        src="product_search.php?tag=pesq&init=<?php echo encode_input($this->Ini->main_page) ?>&session=<?php echo session_id() ?>" 
        width="100%"></iframe>
```

Additionally, the  must have the target="iframe_form" to work.

Comment: If it was recursive iframming, iframe would not stop at 4th level it would go very long. However if recursive, why did not displayed in development environment.

Comment: <iframe id="iframe_form" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0px" marginheight="0px" topmargin="0px" leftmargin="0px" align="center" height="500px" name="iframe_form" scrolling="auto" src="product_search.php?tag=pesq&init=<?php echo encode_input($this->Ini->main_page) ?>&session=<?php echo session_id() ?>" width="100%"></iframe>

Comment: I added the target attribute but still have same problem.